# FOSUserBundle automatically authenticate user with SUPER_ADMIN privileges

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

In my application, `path: /login` from `FOSUserBundle` requires `User` to provide credentials in order to authenticate him.

I want to change authentication behaviour to non-standard:
whenever authentication is required, authenticate user automatically (redirect or skip login) with `SUPER_ADMIN` privileges.

What is a proper way to do it in Symfony 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override FOSUserBundle SecurityController first, after modify loginAction method like that;

```
public function loginAction(Request $request) 
{
    $user  = new User("yourmail@sd.com", "your_pwd", "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN");
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(),'your_security_provider_name', $user->getRoles());

    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    return $this->redirectToRoute('your_custom_route_name');
}
```